# Select events from public calendar

Tags: mac, sync, iphone, calendar, calendar.app

There are some public calendars with many, many events listed. I want to look at the available events and choose a few to import into my personal calendar in iCal. If I subscribe to the public calendar, iCal updates it with new events, but the calendar is read-only: I cannot delete or hide events I am not interested in. I can copy an event and paste it into a local calendar, but I have to remember to remove the invitees or iCal will think I want to send an invitation, and the experience is less than ideal.

I might try using a script to make the operation easier, but perhaps there is a better way to handle this use case. I don't mind if it involves going through Google or Yahoo's calendars, as long as in the end I can manage the events via iCal (on my Mac and iPhone). Can you help?